# Is it necessary to use MongoRepository instead of JPARepository for MongoDB in Spring?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, mongorepository, jparepository

Can't we use JPARepository for MongoDB connection? Is MongoRepository the only way to work with MongoDB? Unable to understand the use of MongoRepository. Does JPARepository don't work in the case of MongoDB? What will happen if I use JPARepository for saving and retrieving values from MongoDB database?